# Android Annotations App does not include generated Activites

Tags: android, android-annotations

I am developing an Android Application with Android Annotations. This worked perfect at the beginning but when I startet to use more and more libraries as dependencies, I got problems to get the App up and running.

I receive the error message

```
01-28 14:53:00.764: E/AndroidRuntime(5471): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{de.mm.aademo.android/de.mm.aademo.android.activity.MainActivity_}:  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "de.mm.aademo.android.activity.MainActivity_" 
on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.mm.aademo.android-14.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/de.mm.aademo.android-14, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

during startup of my application. It seems to be that the generated classes are removed during the gradle build process but I do not know why and when.

To reproduce this issue, I created a sample GitHub Project so that everyone can reproduce this issue. You can find the project at

https://github.com/MichaelMeyersGit/AA_Demo_Project

Maybe someone can see what is wrong with my configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after wasting a lot of time with suspecting Android Annotations or the apt plugin I found the real root cause.

What I forgot to tell is that I am running an Android 4.4.2 (API 19) device and all API versions < 21 have to be prepared to use Multidex.

In my gradle build file I enabled Multidex (I had to) and so I had to create my own Android Application class

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application{

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the target sdk to 25 and build tools to 25.0.2. The problem must be that the Activity is missing from the main dex list due to a bug in older build tools.

Comment: 25 and 25.0.2 does not work for me but when I am using SDK 23 and build tools 23.0.2 my app starts at my device. But still something is missing. I put a @Background Annotation to a method at my MainActivity and now I receive the error message that the class BackgroundExecutor class from Android Annotations cannot be found. I updated the Github Project

Comment: You should not use this old build tools. I built and ran your projects with build tools 25.0.2 and it works fine. Try to clean your project and run it again with new build tools.